# Why isn't my package-patch being preserved in react-scripts?

Tags: reactjs, patch, react-scripts

I've been working around [Issue
#11769](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11769) in `react` and `react-scripts` by editing the `react-scripts` webpack config as suggested [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691873586). The patch works, but is removed upon the following `yarn run start`.

I'm taking the following steps:

1. I `yarn run package-patch react-scripts` after editing `config/webpack.config.js`.
2. The above produces a patch that looks like:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js b/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
index 2b1b3bb..996c465 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
@@ -347,6 +347,12 @@ module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
     module: {
       strictExportPresence: true,
       rules: [
+        {
+          test: /\.m?js/,
+          resolve: {
+            fullySpecified: false
+          }
+        },
         // Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
         shouldUseSourceMap && {
           enforce: 'pre',
```

3. I `yarn run start` and the patch works.
4. I `yarn run start` again and the added config parameters are gone.